# Setting a picturebox to a location automatically VB.net

Tags: vb.net, picturebox

I have a winform that has a pictureboxcontrol, I need set this in the upper right corner (X & Y), but the form is maximized automatically; so I dont know how set the picturebox location automatic, because the main form can have diferent size according the screen where the app is running.

Can any one help me with this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to move the pictureBox at the upper right corner then with the designer or by code set the Anchor:

```
pictureBox1.Anchor = (AnchorStyles.Top | AnchorStyles.Right);
```

Regards :D